# Object mode scaling vs edit mode scaling for video game development

Tags: modeling

When working on video game assets, is it more efficient to model the assets and scaling them in edit mode or rather modify the scale on object mode? Which option is most commonly used by artists? 
For example, creating a table using simple cubes. Is it more efficient for game engines and the PC as a whole to work with the table formed by several cubes with different scales (object mode scale) or rather have all specific scales modified in edit mode while maintaining the x,y,z object scale in 1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there are any significant *efficiency* implications, but I typically try to apply scale when making assets for the BGE, as some discrepancies with physics and collision bounds can occur and very large or small scales can cause precision issues.

For external engines I would apply scale just because of the exporting process (depending on the format, the scale may be applied automatically anyway)

It doesn't really matter whether you scale in edit or object mode as long as you apply it with <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>*> Scale* when all is said and done.